# Tic Tac Toe : simple AI

Tags: javascript

I have a project that consists in creating a tic tac toe game that contains singleplayer and multiplayer. On the multiplayer side, each player will enter his name, and the first player will choose which symbol he will play with, if he chooses x, he will start first , in the case that first player choose 0, the second player will start first. I managed to do the multiplayer part without problems, but on the singleplayer side I don't know how to implement a simple AI that picks random fields. On the singleplayer side I want to keep the same condition, if the player chooses x, he will start first, if he chooses 0, he will start second.I wonder if you can help me.

That is the multiplayer part:

```js
//variabile globale
let x='x';
let o='0';
let player=x;
let player2=o;
let tura=x;
let currentPlayer=x;
let nume1=document.getElementById('nume1').value;
let nume2=document.getElementById('nume2').value;
function showOptions() {
    if (player == o) {
        document.getElementById("rx").checked = false;
        document.getElementById("ro").checked = true;
    }
    else if (player == x) {
        document.getElementById("rx").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("ro").checked = false;
    }
    document.getElementById("optionsDlg").style.display = "block";
}


function getOptions() {
    if (document.getElementById('rx').checked === true) {
        player = x;
        player2 = o;
        tura = player;

    }
    else {
        player = o;
        player2 = x;
        tura = player2;

    }
    document.getElementById("optionsDlg").style.display = "none";
}

function closeModal(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
}

if(player==x)
{
    currentPlayer==player;
}
else{
    currentPlayer==player2;
}

 //stores the status of the game, whether its over or still in play
 let gameStatus = "Game On";

 //Gets all Boxes elements
 const boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

 //loops through all the elements
 for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
   //adds event listener to each box;
   boxes[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
     //checks if the box has an x or an o in it and also checks if the game is still on
     if (boxes[i].innerHTML.trim() == "" && gameStatus == "Game On") {
       //adds x or o for the current play in their choosen box
       boxes[i].innerHTML = currentPlayer;
       let nume1=document.getElementById('nume1').value;
       let nume2=document.getElementById('nume2').value;
       //changes player turns
       currentPlayer = currentPlayer == player ? player2 : player;

       //changes player's turn label on top of the game
       if(currentPlayer==player){
       document.getElementById(
         "player"
       ).innerHTML = nume1.toUpperCase();}
       else{
        document.getElementById(
          "player"
        ).innerHTML = nume2.toUpperCase();}

       //checks 3 matching x's or o's
       if (
         boxes[0].innerHTML == boxes[1].innerHTML &&
         boxes[1].innerHTML == boxes[2].innerHTML &&
         boxes[0].innerHTML.trim() != ""
       ) {
         showWinner(0, 1, 2);
       } else if (
         boxes[3].innerHTML == boxes[4].innerHTML &&
         boxes[4].innerHTML == boxes[5].innerHTML &&
         boxes[3].innerHTML.trim() != ""
       ) {
         showWinner(3, 4, 5);
       } else if (
         boxes[6].innerHTML == boxes[7].innerHTML &&
         boxes[7].innerHTML == boxes[8].innerHTML &&
         boxes[6].innerHTML.trim() != ""
       ) {
         showWinner(6, 7, 8);
       } else if (
         boxes[0].innerHTML == boxes[3].innerHTML &&
         boxes[3].innerHTML == boxes[6].innerHTML &&
         boxes[0].innerHTML.trim() != ""
       ) {
         showWinner(0, 3, 6);
       } else if (
         boxes[1].innerHTML == boxes[4].innerHTML &&
         boxes[4].innerHTML == boxes[7].innerHTML &&
         boxes[1].innerHTML.trim() != ""
       ) {
         showWinner(1, 4, 7);
       } else if (
         boxes[2].innerHTML == boxes[5].innerHTML &&
         boxes[5].innerHTML == boxes[8].innerHTML &&
         boxes[2].innerHTML.trim() != ""
       ) {
         showWinner(2, 5, 8);
       } else if (
         boxes[0].innerHTML == boxes[4].innerHTML &&
         boxes[4].innerHTML == boxes[8].innerHTML &&
         boxes[0].innerHTML.trim() != ""
       ) {
         showWinner(0, 4, 8);
       } else if (
         boxes[2].innerHTML == boxes[4].innerHTML &&
         boxes[4].innerHTML == boxes[6].innerHTML &&
         boxes[2].innerHTML.trim() != ""
       ) {
         showWinner(2, 4, 6);
       }else if(
        (boxes[0].innerHTML != boxes[1].innerHTML!=boxes[2].innerHTML!=
        boxes[3].innerHTML!=boxes[4].innerHTML!=boxes[5].innerHTML!=
        boxes[6].innerHTML!=boxes[7].innerHTML!=boxes[8].innerHTML)
        &&(boxes[0].innerHTML.trim() != "")
        &&(boxes[1].innerHTML.trim() != "")
        &&(boxes[2].innerHTML.trim() != "")
        &&(boxes[3].innerHTML.trim() != "")
        &&(boxes[4].innerHTML.trim() != "")
        &&(boxes[5].innerHTML.trim() != "")
        &&(boxes[6].innerHTML.trim() != "")
        &&(boxes[7].innerHTML.trim() != "")
        &&(boxes[8].innerHTML.trim() != "")
        ){
        roundDraw();
       }
     }
   });
 }

function roundDraw(){
  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML=`Match is a tie`;
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
  gameStatus="Game Over";
  
}

 //resets the game
 document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener("click", function() {
   for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
     boxes[i].innerHTML = "";
     boxes[i].style.backgroundColor = "#dee9ec";
     boxes[i].style.color = "black";
   }
   currentPlayer = "x";
   document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("player").innerHTML = "X";
   gameStatus = "Game On";
 });

 //displays the winner
 function showWinner(x, y, z) {
  let nume1=document.getElementById('nume1').value;
let nume2=document.getElementById('nume2').value;
   boxes[x].style.background = "#0d8b70";
   boxes[x].style.color = "white";
   boxes[y].style.background = "#0d8b70";
   boxes[y].style.color = "white";
   boxes[z].style.background = "#0d8b70";
   boxes[z].style.color = "white";
   if(currentPlayer==player){
    document.getElementById(
      "winner"
    ).innerHTML = nume2.toUpperCase();}
    else{
     document.getElementById(
       "winner"
     ).innerHTML = nume1.toUpperCase();}
   document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
   gameStatus = "Game Over";
 }
```

```css
.container-out {
  font-family: "Fira Sans", sans-serif;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.container-in {
  width: 97%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.table-container {
  margin: 10 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  min-width: 70px;
  min-height: 70px;
  background: #dee9ec;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 900;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.table-container h2 {
  color: #0d8b70;
  display: none;
}

.table-container button {
  border: none;
  background: #13838b;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 15px;
}

.table-container button:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.table-container button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

/* modal background */
.modal {
  
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto; /* enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: black; /* fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

/* modal content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  /* 16 % from the top and centered */
  margin: 16% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 380px;
  max-width: 80%;
}
.modal-content p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* close button for modal dialog */
.close {
  color: rgb(170, 170, 170);
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: -25px;
  right: -10px;
  font-size: 34px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="multiplayer.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-out">
        <div class="container-in">
        <div class="table-container">
            <p>Player <span id="player">X</span> your turn</p>
            <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td><div class="box"></div></td>
                <td><div class="box"></div></td>
                <td><div class="box"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div class="box"></div></td>
                <td><div class="box"></div></td>
                <td><div class="box"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div class="box"></div></td>
                <td><div class="box"></div></td>
                <td><div class="box"></div></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
    
            <h2 id="message">Player <span id="winner"></span> Wins</h2>
            <button id="reset">Reset</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 <!-- The dialog for getting feedback from the user -->
 <!-- <div id="userFeedback" class="modal"> -->
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <!-- <div class="modal-content">
      <p id="questionText"></p>
      <p><button id="yesBtn">Yes</button>&nbsp;<button id="noBtn">No</button></p>
    </div>
  </div> -->
  <!-- The options dialog -->
  <div id="optionsDlg" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h3>Alege simbolul:</h3>
        <input type="text" id="nume1">
        <label><input type="radio" name="player" id="rx" value="x" checked>X (joaca primul)&nbsp;</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="player" id="ro" value="o">O<br></label>
        <input type="text" id="nume2">
        <p><button id="okBtn" onclick="getOptions()">Play</button></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="multiplayer.js"></script>
</html>
```

That is the singleplayer part.I want to use somehow the same code for the files.

```js
//variabile globale
let x='x';
let o='0';
let player=x;
let computer=o;
let tura=x;
let currentPlayer=x;
function showOptions() {
    if (player == o) {
        document.getElementById("rx").checked = false;
        document.getElementById("ro").checked = true;
    }
    else if (player == x) {
        document.getElementById("rx").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("ro").checked = false;
    }
    document.getElementById("optionsDlg").style.display = "block";
}


function getOptions() {
    if (document.getElementById('rx').checked === true) {
        player = x;
        computer = o;
        tura = player;

    }
    else {
        player = o;
        computer = x;
        tura = computer;
       

    }
    document.getElementById("optionsDlg").style.display = "none";
}

function closeModal(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
}




if(player==x)
{
    currentPlayer==player;
}
else{
    currentPlayer==computer;
}

 //stores the status of the game, whether its over or still in play
 let gameStatus = "Game On";

 //Gets all Boxes elements
 const boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

 //loops through all the elements
 for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
   //adds event listener to each box;
   boxes[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
     //checks if the box has an x or an o in it and also checks if the game is still on
     if (boxes[i].innerHTML.trim() == "" && gameStatus == "Game On") {
       //adds x or o for the current play in their choosen box
       boxes[i].innerHTML = currentPlayer;
       //changes player turns
       currentPlayer = currentPlayer == player ? computer : player;

       //changes player's turn label on top of the game
       if(currentPlayer==player){
       document.getElementById(
         "player"
       ).innerHTML = nume1.toUpperCase();}
       else{
        document.getElementById(
          "player"
        ).innerHTML = nume2.toUpperCase();}

       //checks 3 matching x's or o's
       if (
         boxes[0].innerHTML == boxes[1].innerHTML &&
         boxes[1].innerHTML == boxes[2].innerHTML &&
         boxes[0].innerHTML.trim() != ""
       ) {
         showWinner(0, 1, 2);
       } else if (
         boxes[3].innerHTML == boxes[4].innerHTML &&
         boxes[4].innerHTML == boxes[5].innerHTML &&
         boxes[3].innerHTML.trim() != ""
       ) {
         showWinner(3, 4, 5);
       } else if (
         boxes[6].innerHTML == boxes[7].innerHTML &&
         boxes[7].innerHTML == boxes[8].innerHTML &&
         boxes[6].innerHTML.trim() != ""
       ) {
         showWinner(6, 7, 8);
       } else if (
         boxes[0].innerHTML == boxes[3].innerHTML &&
         boxes[3].innerHTML == boxes[6].innerHTML &&
         boxes[0].innerHTML.trim() != ""
       ) {
         showWinner(0, 3, 6);
       } else if (
         boxes[1].innerHTML == boxes[4].innerHTML &&
         boxes[4].innerHTML == boxes[7].innerHTML &&
         boxes[1].innerHTML.trim() != ""
       ) {
         showWinner(1, 4, 7);
       } else if (
         boxes[2].innerHTML == boxes[5].innerHTML &&
         boxes[5].innerHTML == boxes[8].innerHTML &&
         boxes[2].innerHTML.trim() != ""
       ) {
         showWinner(2, 5, 8);
       } else if (
         boxes[0].innerHTML == boxes[4].innerHTML &&
         boxes[4].innerHTML == boxes[8].innerHTML &&
         boxes[0].innerHTML.trim() != ""
       ) {
         showWinner(0, 4, 8);
       } else if (
         boxes[2].innerHTML == boxes[4].innerHTML &&
         boxes[4].innerHTML == boxes[6].innerHTML &&
         boxes[2].innerHTML.trim() != ""
       ) {
         showWinner(2, 4, 6);
       }else if(
        (boxes[0].innerHTML != boxes[1].innerHTML!=boxes[2].innerHTML!=
        boxes[3].innerHTML!=boxes[4].innerHTML!=boxes[5].innerHTML!=
        boxes[6].innerHTML!=boxes[7].innerHTML!=boxes[8].innerHTML)
        &&(boxes[0].innerHTML.trim() != "")
        &&(boxes[1].innerHTML.trim() != "")
        &&(boxes[2].innerHTML.trim() != "")
        &&(boxes[3].innerHTML.trim() != "")
        &&(boxes[4].innerHTML.trim() != "")
        &&(boxes[5].innerHTML.trim() != "")
        &&(boxes[6].innerHTML.trim() != "")
        &&(boxes[7].innerHTML.trim() != "")
        &&(boxes[8].innerHTML.trim() != "")
        ){
        roundDraw();
       }
     }
   });
 }

function roundDraw(){
  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML=`Match is a tie`;
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
  gameStatus="Game Over";
  
}

 //resets the game
 document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener("click", function() {
   for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
     boxes[i].innerHTML = "";
     boxes[i].style.backgroundColor = "#dee9ec";
     boxes[i].style.color = "black";
   }
   currentPlayer = "x";
   document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("player").innerHTML = "X";
   gameStatus = "Game On";
 });

 //displays the winner
 function showWinner(x, y, z) {
  let nume1=document.getElementById('nume1').value;
let nume2=document.getElementById('nume2').value;
   boxes[x].style.background = "#0d8b70";
   boxes[x].style.color = "white";
   boxes[y].style.background = "#0d8b70";
   boxes[y].style.color = "white";
   boxes[z].style.background = "#0d8b70";
   boxes[z].style.color = "white";
   if(currentPlayer==player){
    document.getElementById(
      "winner"
    ).innerHTML = nume2.toUpperCase();}
    else{
     document.getElementById(
       "winner"
     ).innerHTML = nume1.toUpperCase();}
   document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
   gameStatus = "Game Over";
 }

 function computerMove(){
  
}
```

```css
.container-out {
    font-family: "Fira Sans", sans-serif;
    padding: 15px 0;
  }
  
  .container-in {
    width: 97%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .table-container {
    margin: 10 auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .box {
    min-width: 70px;
    min-height: 70px;
    background: #dee9ec;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 900;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .box:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  
  .table-container h2 {
    color: #0d8b70;
    display: none;
  }
  
  .table-container button {
    border: none;
    background: #13838b;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 5px 7px;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 15px;
  }
  
  .table-container button:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  
  .table-container button:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
  
  /* modal background */
  .modal {
    
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto; /* enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: black; /* fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  }
  
  /* modal content */
  .modal-content {
    background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
    color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    /* 16 % from the top and centered */
    margin: 16% auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 380px;
    max-width: 80%;
  }
  .modal-content p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  /* close button for modal dialog */
  .close {
    color: rgb(170, 170, 170);
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
    right: -10px;
    font-size: 34px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .close:hover,
  .close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="singleplayer.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-out">
        <div class="container-in">
        <div class="table-container">
            <p>Player <span id="player">X</span> your turn</p>
            <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td><div class="box"></div></td>
                <td><div class="box"></div></td>
                <td><div class="box"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div class="box"></div></td>
                <td><div class="box"></div></td>
                <td><div class="box"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div class="box"></div></td>
                <td><div class="box"></div></td>
                <td><div class="box"></div></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
    
            <h2 id="message">Player <span id="winner"></span> Wins</h2>
            <button id="reset">Reset</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 <!-- The dialog for getting feedback from the user -->
 <!-- <div id="userFeedback" class="modal"> -->
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <!-- <div class="modal-content">
      <p id="questionText"></p>
      <p><button id="yesBtn">Yes</button>&nbsp;<button id="noBtn">No</button></p>
    </div>
  </div> -->
  <!-- The options dialog -->
  <div id="optionsDlg" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h3>Alege simbolul:</h3>
        <label><input type="radio" name="player" id="rx" value="x" checked>X (joaca primul)&nbsp;</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="player" id="ro" value="o">O<br></label>
        <p><button id="okBtn" onclick="getOptions()">Play</button></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="singleplayer.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Remove this part:

```
//changes player turns
currentPlayer = currentPlayer == player ? computer : player;

//changes player's turn label on top of the game
if(currentPlayer==player){
    document.getElementById(
         "player"
    ).innerHTML = nume1.toUpperCase();}
else{
    document.getElementById(
         "player"
    ).innerHTML = nume2.toUpperCase();}
```

because the computer will do its turn right after the human so it's unnecessary to show its name.
Replace this code with code of the computer's turn, something like this:

```
let randomSquare = Math.floor(Math.random() * boxes.length);
if (boxes[randomSquare].innerHTML.trim() === "") {
    boxes[randomSquare].innerHTML = computer;
}
```

Also add:

```
if (currentPlayer === computer) {
    // same code as above
}
```

below

```
//Gets all Boxes elements
const boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
```

for the case that the computer goes first.

I really recommend that instead of only representing the game board in the HTML, you should represent it first in JavaScript (using an array that contains 3 arrays of size 3 for example) and then after each turn converting this representation into HTML. This will make your code much simpler and more readable.

Comment: They've already said that they're intending to make a simple AI that randomly picks squares. They don't know where to start, however. This makes your post not really an answer...

Comment: Okay, I tried to improve my answer.